# Move/Publish contents and sites between farms

Tags: publishing-site, sharepoint-on-prem, cross-site-publishing

We have 2 physically independent farms. (1:Production  ; 2:Staging ).

we use the setup and architecture here after :

- SharePoint Production farm : two Web Front End's, one APP and one SQL  (4 Virtual Machines)
- SharePoint Staging farm : two Web Front End's, one APP and one SQL  (4 Virtual Machines)

So what I would like to do is Synchronize or publish (Automatically and/or manually) sites or site collection contents from the Staging farm to the production farm.

is it feasible is there any best practices for this kind of process ?

I am completely new to publishing concept and would like to know if there is any article on the same. ? Can anyone explain me the concept of publishing automatically content or sites (with one click) between two farms? If not possible then, what are the best practices for a manual synchronization procedure?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods as far i know.

1. [Cross Site Publishing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2012/09/18/sharepoint-2013-cross-site-publishing-overview/)
2. [Content Deployment.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263423.aspx)

Above method will give you a control on authoring a content in stagging and publish it to the Production.

But if you want to develop a site collection( customize it, apply the permission etc) then move it into the Production then you can use the do the Backup and Restore method.

1. You can take the backup of Site collection and Restore it Production.